# Vietoris-Begle type result for differentiable fiber bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fibration

In Vietoris-Begle Theorem, we consider a closed and surjective map between two paracompact and Hausdorff spaces and we get some relation involving the homologies of the fiber, total space, and the base space. My question is the following.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a differentiable fiber bundle such that the fiber has trivial homology (with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients). Then prove that the induced homomorphism on homology is an isomorphism.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at the Serre spectral sequence?

Comment: Using Serre spectral sequence the results which I have found so far have the hypothesis that the base space is simply connected. I could not find any better result.

Comment: The base does not need to be simply connected.  The language of the spectral sequence is a little simpler in the simply-connected case, but it always exists.  You just have  to use homology with twisted coefficients, or the language of sheaves.